# TCP socket read hangs when wi fi connection breaks

Tags: windows-mobile, tcp, wifi, pocketpc

I am facing peculiar problem with read on TCP sockets when wi fi connectivity goes off and then again reconnects

scenario : i am continously pinging to server on windows pocket PC device over wi fi. 
           when the device is in the area of wifi weak signal strength , socket read blocks indefinately and freezes the device totally and when wi fi signal strength becomes stronger read return and all previous operations on screen is executed.

can anyone give solution to this problem

Comment: Are you sure it's freezing the entire device and not just the read thread or the application? If it's actually freezing the entire device, you have a driver issue and should report it to your manufacturer.

Comment: yeah , entire device freezes . i cant even enter anything in key board

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of TCP -- TCP is reliable, so if there's any sort of network problem (such as a wifi signal loss as you describe), data will be buffered and held until the problem goes away, at which point the data will be sent again and the connection will resume.

You can modify or tune this behavior a bit by changing the TCP timeout values -- if the connection is unable to send data at all for the timeout period (usually 10 minutes by default), then the connection will shut down.  Depending on the API you are using you may be able to change this timeout to be several seconds instead (though be careful of making it too short, which would cause you to drop connections due to more transient network problems.)

It also sounds like you have a problem in your code where the paused connection completely locks up the device -- this is likely caused by holding some lock that you shouldn't while trying to read data from the connection.  Make sure to release ALL locks before doing the socket read (or write).  If you can fix this problem, you may find that you don't care about the TCP timeout.

Comment: Chris, 1. once the tcp connection is broken by physical link problems , after some time if physical link is established then how the data on previously established link gets passed to the socket read (as i understand once physical connection breaks entire tcp context is lost , with new link establishment we need start new start tcp connection and old tcp data will be lost . let me know if i am wrong in my understanding

Comment: 2. i dont have any locks as you said , because tcp read calls follows tcp writes. hence when wifi signal goes down tcp write will be successful but tcp read hangs indefinately till signal strength becomes stronger. my concern is blocking read freezes the device. how can we avoid this

Comment: @sal: the point is that the TCP connection is NOT broken by physical link problems, as long as the physical link comes back before the timeout period (10 minutes or so).  The TCP data is buffered and will be retransmitted and nothing will be lost

Comment: @2: a blocking read only freezes the thread that does the read.  If other threads are also freezing (the device freezes, you say), then the thread that is doing the read must be holding some lock that is causing the other threads to freeze.  Use you debugger to determine why the other threads are frozen.

Comment: chris , its a single thread application , same thread reads data from user and writes to tcp socket.  so when thread is blocked in read and wifi connection breaks , user gets device hanging feel for about 15 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I used to run into similar problems several years ago but I changed my implementation to use Asynchronous Sockets on the Server and on the Handset.  Make sure you're catching the exceptions and tracking how many bytes were read / sent and you can pick backup again after notifying the other endpoint of the "re-established" connection (so that the other party doesn't try to completely start from the beginning agian .... logic you need to add).